# Get IMG tag src from UIWebView as NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiwebview, webview

How can I get the src of images of the current page in the UIWebView and be able to use it as a string later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSString *imgSrcValue = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                @"document.getElementByID('yourImgScrID').value"];
```

Comment: that would only get the source of one image, of which you would have to know the id of.

Comment: @Prince I can't seem to NSLog the imgSrcValue, im on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is parse the HTML for  tags into an array, then extract all the src links into a new array (do this to avoid including other src tags for things like scripts). Bear in mind that some may be ".../image.png" so you will have to convert them into "theWebsiteYouWere.com/browsing/atTheTime/.png"